# HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've added Spring security to my project and configured it as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

     <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/add-job**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login  
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/"
            always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

through the above configuration when I go to `/add-job` it redirects me to `\login` and after login success I go to `/add-job` it shows me error 
[image: Access Denied Message]

is there any mistake I've.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring security is right in denying access:

- you define only one login in your authentication manager: `admin/admin` with one authority **`ROLE_ADMIN`**
- you restrict access to `/add-job**` to users having **`ROLE_USER`** authority

No user can have the `ROLE_USER` authority, so spring security will always deny access.

You should use either `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER` (or any other `ROLE_xxx` you like) but use the same in protecting the resource (`access="hasRole(xxx)"`) and granting to user (`authorities="ROLE_xxx"`)

Anyway, the simplest way to fix is to add the required authority to user admin:

```
        <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
```

Comment: I wanna ask that is the any way to restrict users never reach on login page, but as admin I only have access to login page. Forgive me if I'm wrong but when we deploy the App on the Server there are __Angels and Devils__ using the net so I'm scared some body may Hack my web that is why I'm asking such a question